# Google Chrome bug or something?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var block1 = document.getElementById('block1');
var block2 = document.getElementById('block2');

document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    block1.style.display = 'inline-block';
    block1.className = 'active';


    block2.style.display = 'inline-block';
    block2.offsetLeft; //<----------- look at this
    block2.className = 'active';
})
```

```css
#block1{display:none;width:100px;height:100px;background:red;transition:5s all}
#block2{display:none;width:100px;height:100px;background:green;transition:5s all}

#block1.active, #block2.active{transform:rotateZ(315deg)}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Run</button>
    
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Look at code

**Google Chrome 70.xx (11.2018)**

Let run it on Google Chrome you will see `block2` rotateZ 315deg while `block1` immediately finished transition.

**IE 11 (2015)**

`block1` & `block2` run very well.

Why does it happen? It take me 1h in headache to figure out

***My conclude***

block2.offsetLeft like to force Chrome to calc postion and size of element, so they can transition in next step.
If we don't do that Chrome will calc in next frame render => so `none` to `inline-block` don't run transition (only animation)

Comment: So what's the question? Yes, [triggering a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) will allow your transition to work. No, it's not a Chrome bug (would rather be an IE one if what you state is correct).

Comment: Thank for link. Performance is reason.

Comment: @Kaiido: The question is "Why does it happen?"

Comment: @Kaiido: "Why does it happen? It take me 1h in headache to figure out" Just above the conclusion header. It could either be them thinking aloud, or them actually asking us. I'm just going to go with the latter since they went to the trouble of posting this.

Comment: @Kaiido: That's a good duplicate, thanks. (Never said they were...)

Comment: I don't know that before I always go arround like setTimeout to add transition effect to element.